# Check in trigger if updated columns contain certain column

Tags: sql-server

I would like to check inside a trigger if my "status" column was altered. I tried my luck with UPDATED_COLUMNS, but it gives me updated column indexes and I cannot rely on them as the structure of the table may change in time.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `WHERE` clause that compares this particular column in the `Inserted` (new values) and `Deleted` (old values) pseudo tables - if the values aren't the same, the column was in fact updated by your `UPDATE` statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER YourUpdateTrigger
ON dbo.YourTable
FOR UPDATE
AS
    -- do something useful here....
    SELECT (columns)
    FROM Inserted i
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.PrimaryKeyColumn = d.PrimaryKeyColumn
    -- check if "Status" column has changed in the "UPDATE"
    WHERE i.Status <> d.Status
```